# Computing many shortest paths in graph

Tags: python, igraph, networkx, shortest-path

I have a large (weighted, directed) graph (>100,000 nodes) and I want to compute a large number of random shortest paths in that graph. So I want to randomly select two nodes (let's say k times) and compute the shortest path. One way to do this is using either the networkx or the igraph module and doing a for loop as in

```
pairs=np.random.choice(np.arange(0,len(graph.nodes)), [k,2]) 
for pair in pairs:
    graph.get_shortest_paths(pair[0],pair[1], weights='weight')
```

This works, but it takes a long time. Especially, compared to computing all paths for a particular source node. Essentially, in every iteration the process loads the graph again and starts the process from scratch. So is there a way to benefit from loading the graph structure in to memory and not redoing this in each iteration without computing all shortest paths (which would take too long given that those would be n*(n-1) paths).

Phrased differently, can I compute a random subset of all shortest paths in an efficient way?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Floyd-Warshall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) algorithm? It computes the shortest distance from all nodes to all other nodes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, I mean as far as I understand, the igraph module automatically applies the Floyd-Warshall above a certain number of nodes. But as I said, this still takes a long time, so for my purposes it would be sufficient just to compute a smaller subset of all shortest paths.

Comment: Sorry, just checked. The igraph module at least according to the docs for R package uses Johnson-Dijkstra. According to Wikipedia, Johnson-Dijkstra is O(EV + V2 log V) whereas Floyd-Warshall is O(V3). But disregarding the differences in time complexity, it just takes a long time. In a way, my (naive) question was whether one could benefit from these efficient algorithms but just for a subset of all possible node pairs.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the operations are independent of each other, so running them in parallel could work (pseudocode):

```py
import dask

@dask.delayed
def short_path(graph, pair):
    return graph.get_shortest_paths(pair[0],pair[1], weights='weight')

pairs=np.random.choice(np.arange(0,len(graph.nodes)), [k,2]) 
results = dask.compute(*[short_path(pair) for pair in pairs])
```